# Mysql match all word either from column1 or column2

Tags: regex, mysql

For example: In MySql I have column1 and column2.
How to make sql query that will return all records that contain all search words in either column 1 or column 2.
So far I was using:

```
Select * from table1 where (column1 like '%search from input box%' or column2 like '%search from input box%')
```

Comment: i think you need to break your search word input to single words in your server side languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is `MyISAM`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
WHERE   MATCH(column1) AGAINST ('+search +from +input +box' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
UNION
SELECT  *
FROM    table2
WHERE   MATCH(column2) AGAINST ('+search +from +input +box' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Create a `FULLTEXT INDEX` on `column1` and `column2` (independently) for this to work fast, and adjust `@ft_min_word_len` to match words as short as you need.

If it's not `MyISAM`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   (
        column1 RLIKE '[[:<:]]search[[:>:]]'
        AND column1 RLIKE '[[:<:]]from[[:>:]]'
        AND column1 RLIKE '[[:<:]]input [[:>:]]'
        AND column1 RLIKE '[[:<:]]box[[:>:]]'
        )
        OR
        (
        column2 RLIKE '[[:<:]]search[[:>:]]'
        AND column2 RLIKE '[[:<:]]from[[:>:]]'
        AND column2 RLIKE '[[:<:]]input [[:>:]]'
        AND column2 RLIKE '[[:<:]]box[[:>:]]'
        )
```